# A column could offset some distance down when scroll up and down in StaggeredGridView (PinterestListView)

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, pinterest, viewgroup

I have used StaggeredGridView to show list items like Pintrest list view. [This is the library](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView/blob/master/src/com/origamilabs/library/views/StaggeredGridView.java) [link](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView).

But, second column going down while scrolling up and down.

Original  - [image]

After scrolling - [image]

Answer (score 1):

If your using an earlier version of the library, there was a bug that caused items to scroll out of view. Make sure you've got the latest version of the library.

If that doesn't resolve your issue, you can try one of these libraries instead:

- [etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid)
- [kiteflo/Android_StaggeredView](https://github.com/kiteflo/Android_StaggeredView)

Then, if all else fails, you can try one of these other suggestions (borrowed from [justinmccandless.com](http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Pinterest-Style+Staggered+Masonry+List+in+Android)):

#### 1. Just Use a [Grid List](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html)

Grid Lists might not be exactly what you're looking for, but they are natively supported by Google with all of the stability that that entails. If you can get by without having offset rows of different sizes, this is a very easy and solid way to go. Check out Android's default Gallery app to see what this looks like, and see the [Grid List documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html) for more.

#### 2. Try a Modified GridView with [Staggered Grid View](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView)

This Github project provides a pretty near clone of what Google was trying to do with their native staggered GridView. It's a widely used and well supported project, but watch out for the absense of an onItemClick method (as of this writing). It is also lacking support for a scroll listener, but there does exist a [fork that supports it](https://github.com/GoMino/StaggeredGridView).

#### 3. Try a Modified List with [Pinterest Like Adapter View](https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView)

This project modifies a more typical List, making it pretty easy to drop in if you are already using something similar. Performance is pretty snappy and it looks fine, but this project also lacks onItemClick support. If you can get by using buttons in your views like in the example, then this is a pretty solid option.

#### 4. Or Try Two Synced List Views with [Pinterest List View](https://github.com/vladexologija/PinterestListView)

This project has a good level of support, but it suffers from a few performance issues. I started to see laggy scrolling in a test with 12+ medium resolution photos. You also might notice some unexpected jerks between the two columns when scrolling rapidly up or down. However, if your list is short and simple like in the example, you might be able to get by using this.

Comment: I have updated the library but still I have the same issue with staggered gridview. Any other suggestions? @Okuma.Scott

Answer (score 0):

create StaggeredGridLayoutManager and set layout manager to recycler view again and after that set Adapter as i mentioned below

> staggeredGridLayoutManager= new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
>   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);
>
> recyclerView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
>   rcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();